# Order of meromorphic function as ratio of two complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $p(z), q(z)\in\mathbb{C}$ be polynomials with no common roots. Define $$f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}.$$ Show that:
>   (a) there are only finitely many points $z\in\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that $\text{ord}_z(f)\neq 0$; and (b) $$\sum_{z\in\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}} \text{ord}_z(f) = 0$$

For (a), I know that $\text{ord}_{\infty}(f(z)) = \text{ord}_0(f(1/z))$. Moreover, $f$ is clearly a rational function, so we can write $f(z) = a_nz^n + \cdots + a_1z+a_0$ with $a_n\neq 0$.

Then, $f(1/z)$ has a pole at $z_0 = 0$ and $\text{ord}_0(f(1/z))=-n=\text{ord}_{\infty}(f(z))=-\deg(f(z))$.

We then have $\text{ord}_{\infty}(f(z)) = \text{ord}_{\infty}(p(z)) - \text{ord}_{\infty}(q(z)) = \deg(q(z))-\deg(p(z))$.

I think I'm on the right track, but I can't quite see where to go from here.

For (b), I have no idea. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that if $g$ and $h$ are meromorphic functions (not identically $0$), then $\operatorname{ord}_z \frac{g}{h} = \operatorname{ord}_z g - \operatorname{ord}_z h$.